# HTML 5 Issues with showing google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have been looking at the google maps html5/javascript code and am attempting to make a app which finds someone current location through longitude and latitude then geo reverses it to give then their address. However when i run the code it just gives a blank screen. I am really new to html5 and if anyone could point to me what i am doing wrong i would be really grateful.

Comment: Can I ask why you delete your code? If you think it was an easy problem and decided to remove code, why don't you just delete your post? Otherwise why don't you keep the code visible on your question and mark the relevant answer as accepted? P.S. we can see your code in edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(): must be  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

Comment: I don't understand, you have given the answer you say is wrong as the right answer???

Comment: you have : instead of ;

Comment: Sorry!! ive been looking at this all-day and have lost the ability to see!!.

Answer (score 0):

By default, navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() has a timeout value of infinite.  In the getCurrentPosition's options parameter, specify a timeout value and I think you will find that is where your error lies.

```
 ... }, function() {
  handleNoGeolocation(true);
}, { timeout: 4000 });
```

Comment: No it is still a blank screen.

Comment: Is the success function being called?  Are you receiving any javascript errors?

Comment: I am not getting any warnings about errors just a blank screen. I am using the intel xdk.

Comment: If you put an alert in your success function, are you seeing it?  a jsfiddle would help..